# `Not a directory: '/home/sagemaker-user/XXX` Error downloading wheelfiles from s3 to SageMaker studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I uploaded a couple of packages (`tar.gz` and `whl` files) to s3, I'd like to download them to a Juypter noteook inside SageMaker Studio.

When i run `aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/dependencies/ dependencies_from_s3/` it keeps giving me error
`download failed: s3://bucket-name/dependencies/ to dependencies_from_s3/ [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/sagemaker-user/dependencies_from_s3/.3f67xxx' -> '/home/sagemaker-user/dependencies_from_s3/'`

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add *recursive* option to your command to copy multiple files

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/dependencies/ ./dependencies_from_s3/ --recursive
```